# C# data storing cut the inputs

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, stored-procedures

I have function where I store my form inputs to database but the problem is it cuts off all inputs to single letter when storing them.

**For instance:** If I write `Tom` as of the name it saves only `t`. And this happens for all inputs in my form.

`Code`

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYAPPDatabaseString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertUser", cn))
        {
            if (nameInput.Text != "" && passwordLableG.Text != "" && usernameLableG.Text != "")
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserType", typeLAbleG.SelectedItem); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", nameInput.Text); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordLableG.Text); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", usernameLableG.Text); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phoneLableG.Text); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCard", idCardLableG.Text); // <-- only stores first letter of input
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    StringBuilder errorMessages = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
            "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
            "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
            "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
            "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
}
```

Here is my `Stored Procedure`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
    @Name VARCHAR,
    @UserType VARCHAR,
    @Password VARCHAR,
    @UserName VARCHAR,
    @Phone VARCHAR = null,
    @IdCard VARCHAR = null
AS
    begin
    INSERT into Users(Name, UserType, Password, UserName, Phone, IdCard) values (@Name,@UserType,@Password,@UserName, @Phone, @IdCard);
    end
```

And here is my `table schema`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserType] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Password] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]    VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [IdCard]   VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Maybe your input parameters for the stored procedure should be varchar(100) instead of just varchar.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I posted it.

Comment: I would go with the answer below.

Comment: @David.Warwick unfortunately adding `(100)` to my procedure didn't fix the issue.

Comment: By the way, if you are using a connection like you are with the using keyword, which is good, you don't need to explicitly close it with the close method.

Comment: @David.Warwick the answer below was fixing code I just happened to make it in debug file :D thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to adjust the store procedures variables length to match with the table.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
        @Name VARCHAR(100),
        @UserType VARCHAR(100),
        @Password VARCHAR(100),
        @UserName VARCHAR(100),
        @Phone VARCHAR(100) = null,
        @IdCard VARCHAR(100) = null
    AS
        begin
        INSERT into Users(Name, UserType, Password, UserName, Phone, IdCard) values (@Name,@UserType,@Password,@UserName, @Phone, @IdCard);
        end

   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertUser", cn))
    {
        if (nameInput.Text != "" && passwordLableG.Text != "" && usernameLableG.Text != "")
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = typeLAbleG.SelectedItem;             
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nameInput.Text;              
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordLableG.Text;             
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usernameLableG.Text;             
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = phoneLableG.Text;               
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdCard", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idCardLableG.Tex;              
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, that is strange. Have you set a breakpoint to examine the parameters that are being passed to the command?

Comment: Thank you, it works, my first attempt was on debug DB file which was deleted on run :D

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting appropriate values for the variables in the stored procedure and executing the insert query from ssm's? What gets inserted into the table when you do that?